# Big Query issues: Im getting both a column name ambiguous error or unrecognized name if I specify table in SELECT

Tags: sql

I am a beginner, but I am a little stumped as to why I keep getting errors. I thought specifying the table would work. Do I have to specify the database as well? If I have to add my project name 'April-17' also I will loose my mind.

```
SELECT departments.department_id
FROM april-17.employee_data.departments d
FULL JOIN april-17.employee_data.employees e
ON d.department_id=e.department_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
SELECT d.department_id
FROM departments d
FULL JOIN employees e
ON d.department_id=e.department_id
```

If you only have `SELECT department_id` it won't know which table you want `department_id` from (could be `d` or could be `e`), hence the "ambiguous" error message. But you have aliased the table to `d` so you also can't use `SELECT departments.department_id`, hence the "unrecognized name" error message.

Comment: Yes: Aliases rename the table within the query: the table `departments` no longer exists as a table selected from, only `d` exists within the query.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean your database name? What errors are you getting? I will re-write your query, I hope you find this useful

```
SELECT <insert list of field you want select here> FROM departments d JOIN employee_data e on d.department_id = e.department_id
```